# How to create multiple KPI's in a row

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, kpi

I want to create multiple kpi's in one row. Example: Charlotte office and then a kpi for phones, a kpi for internet, a kpi electricity, etc all side by side with the appropriate headers. Basically I would have each office and then a kpi for those critical things. I've researched and I'm not sure that you can do that out of the box. Please help.  It also doesnt seem to let you change the header name 'Status'.

Answer (score 0):

You could create multiple calculated columns of the type **number** for each column you want a KPI for. For this you need a choice column for every subject, like one for internet, one for phones etc.

In this example, i have created one choice column (internetStatus) with 3 different choices and one calculated column (internetKPI) based on the previous column. The values in internetStatus are:

- Available
- Not Available
- Unknown

and the calculation in the second column is:

```
="<center>"&IF([internetStatus]="Available","<img src='http://sharepoint/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-0.GIF' border='0'/>"
,IF([internetStatus]="Not Available","<img src='http://sharepoint/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-1.GIF' border='0'/>",
IF([internetStatus]="Unknown","<img src='http://sharepoint/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-2.GIF' border='0'/>","")))&"</center>"
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

The values you need to change is the following in every row:

```
([ColumnNameGoesHere]="ColumnValueGoesHere","<img src='http://SiteURLGoesHere/_layouts/images/KPIDefault-0.GIF'
```

And based on the sites regional settings, you might need to replace every "," in the calculation with ";".

Comment: Thank you user19952 for the quick and detailed response but I want to have a kpi next to the internetkpi like phonekpi, electricitykpi. One column Charlotte office and then internetkpi, phonekpi, electricitykpi. Next Row Houston office and then internetkpi, phonekpi, electricitykpi. etc. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Yes, just create three choice columns and then three calculated columns based on the choice columns. Then you can hide the choice columns from the listview and only display the calculated ones.

Comment: I originally declared you answer as correct but after going through it. It does not work. Please someone help. Why does SP make formatting kpi's so restrictive and byzantine...

Comment: What did not work? You just wanna add a calculated column for each column that you need a KPI for, then modify the above calculation to suit the specific targeted column.